# How to get SOAP attributes in PHP?

Tags: php, soap

Using the example below, how should I parse for the "HotelCode" attribute of "HotelRef"?

```
<OTA_HotelAvailRQ Version="1.0" TimeStamp="2005-08-01T09:30:47+02:00" EchoToken="fb57388d" AvailRatesOnly="true" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
     <AvailRequestSegments>
        <AvailRequestSegment AvailReqType="Room">
           <HotelSearchCriteria>
              <Criterion>
                 <HotelRef HotelCode="HOTEL1"/>
              </Criterion>
           </HotelSearchCriteria>
        </AvailRequestSegment>
     </AvailRequestSegments>
  </OTA_HotelAvailRQ>
```

I'm able to get a response from SOAP server, see below for the output but notice the HotelRef is empty. How do I access the attribute?

`stdClass Object
(
    [AvailRequestSegments] => stdClass Object
        (
            [AvailRequestSegment] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [HotelSearchCriteria] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Criterion] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [HotelRef] => 
                                )`

Comment: Pray to bejesus that you are not accessing a .net soap service with php. (they tend to use a non standard compliant version of soap, and no php soap libraries will mesh with them)

Comment: I don't believe the vendor is on .NET as they warn there may be issues with clients using .NET

Answer (score 0):

```
$strXML = 'theRequestXML_OTA_HotelAvailRQ';
$objSimpleXML = new SimpleXMLElement($strXML,NULL,NULL,"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
foreach ($objSimpleXML->children() as $objItems) {

    $strHotelCode = $objItems->AvailRequestSegments->AvailRequestSegment->HotelSearchCriteria->Criterion->HotelRef->attributes()->{'HotelCode'};
}
```